# Bounded holomorphic functions in unbounded domain

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $D$ be an unbounded pseudoconvex domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$. I would like to study the peak set of $D$.

1)Can the peak set of $D$ be empty? Or

2) Does $D$ always admit a nonconstant bounded holomorphic function?

Any reference or idea or example will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is an example.

Let $f\in O(\mathbb{C})$ be holomorphic. Set $D=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2, |w|< e^{-\Re(f(z))}\}$. It is well known that $D$ is unbounded and pseudoconvex. Set $F(z,w)=we^{f(z)}$ then $|F|<1$ and is holomorphic in $D$.

Comment: For 2) do you mean a bounded holomorphic function which cannot be extended beyond D?  Otherwise, constant functions work.  Also, if D is all of C^2, then constant functions are the only examples by Louisville.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I mean a non-constant bounded holomorphic function. Whether it extends or not  beyond $D$ is not important.

Comment: @StevenGubkin... Liouville = Louisville?

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: When I taught at Wisconsin, I once put on a true-false question that Liouville was a former quarterback for the Badgers. One student thought it was true.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar  Yup!  Unfortunately I cannot edit that unsightly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MR0549981 (81b:32005) 
Diederich, Klas; Sibony, Nessim
Strange complex structures on Euclidean space.
J. Reine Angew. Math. 311/312 (1979), 397–407.

In this paper, the authors construct various examples of Stein (hence pseudoconvex) open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^2$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ and not isomorphic with $\mathbb{C}^2$. One such example $\Omega_3$ has the property that there is no nonconstant bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega_3$.